# Language that uses [t] (or [k]?) in formal settings and [k] (or [t]?) in in informal

Tags: list-of-languages

I remember reading about some language in which both [t] and [k] were considered the same phoneme and one of the [t] and [k] were used in formal and the other in informal settings. Does such a language exist or was what I read a myth? I apologize for being vague but I have no other information about that language and it is bugging me.

Answer (score 18):

There are a few Polynesian languages such as [Hawaiian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_language) and [Samoan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoan_language) that don't contrast [t] and [k] i.e. [t] and [k] exist as allophones of /t/.

The language you're looking for seems to be **Samoan** where /t/ is pronounced [k] in colloquial speech and [t] in formal speech.

Answer (score 1):

K (Depending on the person) is used in everyday speech, though T is used to greet people formerly. So, T is replaced with K, similar to how [Tongans](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=0de3a1c2368da6d3JmltdHM9MTY3OTUyOTYwMCZpZ3VpZD0yMjgwODYwMS1mM2NmLTZlM2YtMmY1Zi05NGRjZjI5NTZmZjAmaW5zaWQ9NTIyMw&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=22808601-f3cf-6e3f-2f5f-94dcf2956ff0&psq=tongans&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvVG9uZ2E&ntb=1) replace the sound of their Ts with a D, but in [Samoa](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=132131529cdf557eJmltdHM9MTY3OTUyOTYwMCZpZ3VpZD0yMjgwODYwMS1mM2NmLTZlM2YtMmY1Zi05NGRjZjI5NTZmZjAmaW5zaWQ9NTIyNg&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=22808601-f3cf-6e3f-2f5f-94dcf2956ff0&psq=samoa&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvU2Ftb2E&ntb=1) you can choose to speak which ever style you like depending on the situation.

Comment: Hi, Hamo, and welcome to the site! Which language are you referring to in this answer? Samoan?